# how to load pictures from json array?

Tags: jquery, image, json, load

i am wondering how to load a couple of images from a json file into an `li`?
here is the json file

```
[
{"id":"1",
 "link":"11.jpg",
}
{"id":"2",
 "link":"12.jpg",
}
{"id":"3",
 "link":"13.jpg",
}
]
```

and i have an `<ul id="links"></ul>`

I've tried this, but without success:

```
$.getJSON("feed.json", loadImage);
 function loadImage(data) {
 $.each(data.link, function(i,item){
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item).appendTo("#links");
 });
 }
```

any ideas?

edit: even with `item` still doesn't work . The images are in the same folder

Comment: what do u get when u log `data`? (to console)

Comment: are the images stored in the same base folder that the jquery is in? or are they in a different folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with you could try defining the loadImage function before you use it. Anyway, it should look more like that:

```
$.getJSON("feed.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.link).appendTo("#links");
    }
});
```

Comment: i don't have to use it, i could say `$.getJSON("feeds.json",
 function (data) {
 $.each...
});` but still wont work

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `item` parameter in the `each` function instead of `data.link`. Because `item` refers to the current item you're iterating over.

Change:

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", data.link).appendTo("#links");
```

To the following:

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", item.link).appendTo("#links"); // Changed data.link to item.link
```

Try tracing `item` in the `each` function.

Comment: @Patrioticcow: What **did** `item` return? Is `data.items` even an array?

Comment: actually it should be `data.link`.  the json file is an array. And i'm thinking `item.link` should be just `item`....???

Comment: @Patrioticcow: If data.link is an array then in the `each` function `item` will be the current object you are iterating over, with the properties `id` and `link`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("feed.json", loadImage);
 function loadImage(data) {
 $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.link).appendTo("#links"); //use item.link. 
 )};
}
```