# JSON image upload to page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

In my ASP.NET MVC4 project I use library jQuery. I define EF code first model.
Database has model like

```
public class Description{
  public int Id{}
  public string Name{}
  public byte[] Img{}
}
```

Pictures store in field "Img".
And I cannot understand how to return this picture for representation while using AJAX query. Controller gives me JSONresult and I get JSON in representation. How I can get picture from it and insert it for example in div. Please give me advise. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the JSON you are receiving. Print it out as a string so that you can examine its structure.

Comment: I define class in my project for json responce
class responce{
 public string name{}
 public byte[] Img{}
}
and in my controller i create action
public JsonResult GetImage(){
  var val = LINQ_QUERY_TO_DATABASE
  return Json(new responce{name = val.name,Img = val.image}, JsonReq.....);
}

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the answer to this question: [how to load pictures from json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542131/how-to-load-pictures-from-json-array)

It appears that your javascript will need to iterate over the bytes and append them to the image data back over in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, i do not have "link" item in my array. I have JSON answer from server as [{name:bla-bla-bla, Img:[63,65,.....]]
In this answer picture  is perform by byte array. I cannot undestand how to use union array as a src field of img tag on a page.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you've actually tried to do?